# SSL VirtualHost not using DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, cloudflare, certificate

I'm trying to set up a self-signed SSL certificate between my own VPS and Cloudflare (next to [Full SSL](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-Off-Flexible-SSL-Full-SSL-Full-SSL-Strict-mean-)). I'm using the following VirtualHosts for this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/public/www

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

But whenever I try to access domain.com it returns a `403 Forbidden` and I get the following error in my apache2 logs:

```
[Fri Jan 30 00:19:23 2015] [error] [client (ip)] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/public/
```

Meaning it tries to access the default DocumentRoot as set in `apache2.conf`:

```
ServerAdmin server@domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/public
```

Note that it *does* work when I change the port of the second VirtualHost to 80 and comment the 3 lines about SSL.

So my question is: why is not using the DocumentRoot that I specified in the VirtualHost (`*:433`)?

**EDIT**

When I pause Cloudflare and go to https://www.domain.com I can access it (of course with a warning because the certificate is self-signed). So maybe it has something to do with Cloudflare?

Comment: Where is the rest of your configuration?

Comment: What part/files do you need? Everything else is pretty much default.

Comment: There's probably a `<Directory /var/www/public>` (or for `/var/www`) somewhere, what's it have?  Are there `.htaccess` files in any of these directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you have to enable NameVirtualHost for the SSL port.
It can be done by editing the file /etc/apache2/ports.conf.
There you can see the configuration for port 80:

> NameVirtualHost *:80
>   Listen 80

You can also see the IFmodule mod_ssl.c tags.
By default there should only be "Listen 443" inside the tags and you just have to add "NameVirtualHost *:443" above the "Listen 443" line. I believe this should fix your issue.

Apparently I don't have the reputation to post images, so here you go:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSA4u.png

EDIT: Don't forget to restart Apache.

Comment: I'm now getting the warning `NameVirtualHost *:433 has no VirtualHosts` while I did change the second VirtualHost to `433`.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I mistyped `443` as `433`.

Comment: This does seem to do it when I pause Cloudflare. As soon as I enable Cloudflare again I run into the same `403 Forbidden` error... I also contact Cloudflare with the same question and a link to this thread.

Comment: If it works without Cloudflare it could be an issue with Cloudflare's caching. It might be showing you an cached version of your page from when it didn't work. (It's been a while since I've used Cloudflare, but sounds like a caching issue)

Comment: I believe there is a flush cache option somewhere in Cloudflare's control panel, I'd try that.